# Storing localStorage.getItem in an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 6 checkboxes on my HTML page. Upon form submission, I want to save in localStorage which ones are checked and which ones are not checked. This is my code:

```
var getmealpref;
for(var i=0, l=checkboxes.length; i<l;i++)
{
    if(checkboxes[i].checked)
    {
        localStorage.setItem('mealpref',checkboxes[i].value);
        getmealpref[i] = localStorage.getItem('mealpref');
        alert(getmealpref[0])
        okay=true;
    }
}
```

I think I am trying to achieve it the wrong way. Is there any method of defining an array for localStorage.getItem?

Answer (score 1):

You must serialize non-string types before storing in localStorage.

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
var getmealpref = [];
for(var i=0, l=checkboxes.length; i<l;i++) {
    if(checkboxes[i].checked) {
        getmealpref[i] = checkboxes[i].value;
        localStorage.mealpref = JSON.stringify(getmealpref);
    }
}

// debug
getmealpref = JSON.parse(localStorage.mealpref);
alert(getmealpref[0]);
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/UD4Bk/2

Comment: Note, the browser should serialize non-string values for you, but you might as well do it yourself.

Comment: [StorageAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) -- Afraid not.  Those functions take a `string` so the caller must handle all serialization.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher -- I believe most browsers do `.toString()` on non-strings, not very useful to us here.

Answer (score 0):

localStorage will accept arrays, but they will be stored as strings so you're better off storing JSON

```
var getmealpref = [];

for(var i=0, l=checkboxes.length; i<l;i++) {
    getmealpref[i] = checkboxes[i].checked;
}

localStorage.setItem('getmealpref', JSON.stringify(getmealpref));
```

to reset them to the stored values

```
var values = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('getmealpref') );

for(var i=0, l=checkboxes.length; i<l;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = values[i];
}
```

Comment: how can i show individual values of 'getmealpref' ? This is my code now:

` var getmealpref = [];
    for(var i=0, l=checkboxes.length; i<l;i++)
    {
        if(checkboxes[i].checked)
        {  
   getmealpref[i] = checkboxes[i].value;  
            okay=true;
        }
    }
 localStorage.setItem('getmealpref', JSON.stringify(getmealpref));
 var getmealpref = localStorage.getItem('getmealpref');
 alert (getmealpref);`